# qt windows share

Tags: c++, qt, networking

I want to make an application in qt 4.7.4 where I need to use shared folders in Windows.

I have searched around and found that I can use QDir(hostName), but there is a problem:
I can't control the bandwidth used. I'd like to be able to set the max transfer rate when
accessing a host in the network.

More about the app: I have a folder on my computer whose content I wish to be identical on all the hosts(who's name will be provided from a file) in my network . For example if I add a new file in that folder and run the app, it should start copying the file in the hosts with the max bandwidth used specified by me.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that bandwidth manages by operating system drivers or services like QoS or firewalls. QDir use only interface provided by operating system to access directory. It works fine with shared dir only because of Windows shared dir behaves the same way as usual dir.

By the way you may try control bandwidth manually by implementing your own file copy procedure. Sorry if my solution too naive or doesn't fit. You may open file (see `QFile`) in shared directory for read-only and open file on local machine in write-only.  Next you start reading portions of data from shared file by timer (see `QTimer`). So you can specify how often you want to copy portions of data (`QTimer` parameter) and how many bytes of data you copy per time (`QIODevice::read` function parameter).

Comment: It is indeed a solution but it's still tricky since I'd have to consider some exceptional cases such as lost connection and check manually for that. Also how would I know that the bytes had transferred and not lost on the way? I was expecting that Qt had something like this already implemented.

Comment: It's a reasonable start, it breaks down when the real bandwidth limits are similar to the max specified bandwidth. Instead, check after each chunk whether you are using too much bandwidth (transferred so far/time used so far), and only in that case use a `QTimer` for a period (transferred so far/max rate - time used so far).

Comment: @QtLearner: TCP/IP already handles byte loss for you, without bothering you. Since it's fairly rare (10E-9 packet loss for Ethernet), resending has hardly any impact on bandwitdh.

Comment: @MSalters Well are you sure that if I use QFile, TCP will be used?

Comment: @QtLearner: `QFile` just asks Windows. It doesn't even care whether a file is local (and uses SATA not TCP) or remote. Windows by default uses TCP for remote file shares.

Comment: Thank you, I'll start implementing the solution.